# Multiple output with bash command

Tags: bash

I want to find the 2 version of python. If I write:

```
{python2,python3}" --version; "
```

I am expecting it to run:

`python2 --version; python3 --version;`

and provide me the versions like if I would have written the above  line directly :

```
Python 2.7.18 
Python 3.8.10
```

but instead I get:

```
python2 --version;: command not found
```

even though if I test the output with:

```
echo {python2,python3}" --version"
```

I do get the expected:

```
python2 --version; python3 --version;
```

Trying

```
`echo {python2,python3}" --version"`
```

didn't work either.
Why? How do I make it work?

Comment: can you provide a bit of context? what is this? part of a bash script? do you always check the same (python 2 and 3) or some others too? Why can't you run it normally instead of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not what it does. You are creating two quoted strings `"python2 --version; "` and `"python3 --version; "` neither of which is a valid command. You could get around that with `eval` but ... [that way lies madness.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

```
# XXX DON'T
eval python{2,3}" --version;"
2.7.18
Python 3.8.10
```

The (not so) simple but straightforward solution would be something like

```
for v in 2 3; do
    python$v --version
done
```

or if you are hellbent on using a wildcard, run a subshell:

```
echo python{2,3}" --version;" | bash
```

Perhaps notice the (lack of) difference between

```
echo python2" --version; "
```

and

```
echo "python2 --version; "
```

The quotes simply tell the shell to keep things together as a single string. (For what it's worth, the shell removes the quotes as part of its parsing process, so the argument to `echo` does not contain any actual quotes, just the parsed string from between the quotes.)

It's *possible* to have command names with literal spaces in them, but incredibly cumbersome; so you don't see this much in practice.

For fun, maybe try

```
# Have a directory in your PATH which is in your home directory
# If you don't, maybe create $HOME/bin and add it to your PATH
bash$ echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | grep "$HOME"
/users/you/bin

bash$ cat >"$HOME/bin/python2 --version"
#!/bin/sh
exec python2 --version
^D

bash$ chmod +x "$HOME/bin/python2 --version"

bash$ "python2 --version"
2.7.18
```

(Maybe delete the script when you're done experimenting.)

Comment: But then why does: echo {python2,python3}" --version;" | bash provides the correct answer?

Comment: It's similar to the `eval` case, except you are creating a new subprocess to run the commands. The quotes are stripped before `echo` runs, as you can easily establish experimentally.

Comment: But when you pipe you simply pushing the string "python2 --version; python3 --version" and therefore that should be similar to: bash "python2 --version; python3 --version" , but that does not work!

Comment: Because the argument to `bash` should be a file name. Try `bash -c "python2 --version; python3 --version;"`. Updated the answer to include this variant.

Comment: Actually: bash -c python{2,3}" --version;" does not work! It only gives the version of python2!

Comment: Oops, hang on, it ends up with two arguments to `-c` ... I'll try to come up with a better fix.